# Failed loading config file

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, protractor

Getting error while running build from Jenkins with Git source. This config file is working fine from local terminal though. Can someone please help?

```
[13:07:10] Using gulpfile ~/.jenkins/workspace/Demo/gulpfile.js
[13:07:10] Starting 'test'...
[13:07:10] Testing sites/sitename
[13:07:10] E/configParser - error code: 105
[13:07:10] E/configParser - description: failed loading configuration file ./sites/sitename/protractor.conf.js

/Users/akuchhal/.jenkins/workspace/Demo/node_modules/protractor/built/configParser.js:130
            throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configuration file ' + filename);
```

This is what I have in Jenkins shell command:

```
npm install;
node_modules/.bin/gulp test --site sitename --suite smoke;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this resolved. I was not including `node_modules` directory in my GIT repository.

Comment: That's strange, you shouldn't include node_modules in your repo; no ?